# Splinter (PhantomJS) throwing error

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I'm getting this error when running my Splinter script

Error:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'",)
in <bound method Service.__del__ of 
<selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service.Service object at 0x7fa709da3fd0>> ignored
```

Even though none of my code even uses the attribute `close`.

Code:

```
 from splinter import Browser

 browser = Browser('phantomjs')
 browser.visit('https://example.com/')
```

I also tried adding `browser.driver.close()` to the end, and that did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

Does the browser window open and show https://example.com? If it does, then you may just need a different version of the phantomjs executable (phantomjs.exe, assuming you're running on Windows).
A close message in general is not surprising, as there is an implied close of the browser when the program ends. This may be a compatibility issue between the version of splinter and the phantomjs executable in your path.
And though it may not be your issue, you do need to have a separate phantomjs executable in your path. You can do a search on "phantomjs download" to learn more.
If you're not sure whether the headless browser is opening, you can add a simple print statement like 
`print(browser.html)`
 to your code to see what happens in the command prompt window.